# Появление дочерних checkbox при нажатии на тег <span>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не силен в jQuery(JavaScript): как реализовать появление дочерних checkbox при нажатии на на тег ?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span><input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">1.</span></th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][1][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.1.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][2][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.2.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td class="check"><input name="chk[1][3][0]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>1.3.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: нажатие на какой тэг-то?

Comment: <span class="arrow"></span>, там будет стрелка через css отображаться

Comment: если на `arrow` то первичный чекбокс меняться не будет - не самый лучший вариант... лучше все-таки при изменении чекбокса

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаем, что в форме у вас несколько таких групп.

Нужно присвоить имя группе. Видимый чекбокс будет иметь имя группы. И то же имя будет приписано каждой строке невидимых чекбоксов.

На нажатие привязваем событие, которое беред имя группы нажатого чекбокса и включает/выключает остальные.

Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[groupName]').bind('click', function() {
    var thisGroupName = $(this).attr('groupName');
    $('tr[groupName=' + thisGroupName + ']').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="left-th"><span class="arrow"></span>
        <input class="groupswitchchb" type="checkbox" groupName="group1">
      </th>
      <th class="right-th"><span class="dashed-span">1.</span>
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;" groupName="group1">
      <td class="check">
        <input name="chk[1][1][0]" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>1.1.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;" groupName="group1">
      <td class="check">
        <input name="chk[1][2][0]" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>1.2.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;" groupName="group1">
      <td class="check">
        <input name="chk[1][3][0]" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>1.3.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Обратите внимание на `groupName="group1"` в чекбоксе и в `tr`.

Также обратите вниамние вот на эту строчку: `$('input[groupName]').bind('click'`. Это заставит нашу функцию срабатывать при нажатии на любой `input`, у которого есть параметр `groupName`. Таким образом все ваши группы в форме будут работать одинаково. Главное следить за правильными именам групп и привязкой к объектам